# yarn install inside docker image with yarn workspaces

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

I am using yarn workspaces and I have this packages in my package.json:

```
  "workspaces": ["packages/*"]
```

I am trying to create a docker image to deploy and I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# production dockerfile
FROM node:9.2

# add code
COPY ./packages/website/dist /cutting

WORKDIR /cutting

COPY package.json /cutting/
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile && yarn cache clean --production

CMD npm run serve
```

But I get the following error:

> error An unexpected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@cutting%2futil: Not found"

`@cutting/util` is the name of one of my workspace packages.

So the problem is that there is no source code in the docker image so it is trying to install it from yarnpkg.

what is the best way to handle workspaces when deploying to a docker image.

Comment: What does the `dist` folder contains here? @Glogo

Comment: dist is the bundled javascript, css and index.html of the webpack build

Comment: Any sample project git repo, I can try on.

Comment: One possible solution would be to copy the package directly to docker image `RUN yarn add file:./@cutting/util` but there must be better way

Comment: i ended up publishing npm packages and going that route

Answer (score 5):

This code won't work outside of the docker vm, so it will refuse in the docker, too.

The problem is you have built a code, and copy the bundled code. The yarn workspaces is looking for a `package.json` that you don't have in the `dist` folder. The workspaces is just creating a link in a common `node_modules` folder to the other workspace that you are using. The source code is needed there. (BTW why don't you build code inside the docker vm? That way source code and dist would also be available.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my dockerfile. I use yarn workspaces and lerna, but without lerna should be similar. You want to build your shared libraries and then test the build works locally by running your code in your dist folder.

```
###############################################################################
# Step 1 : Builder image
FROM node:11 AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN npm i -g yarn
RUN npm i -g lerna
COPY ./lerna.json .
COPY ./package* ./
COPY ./yarn* ./
COPY ./.env .
COPY ./packages/shared/ ./packages/shared
COPY ./packages/api/ ./packages/api
# Install dependencies and build whatever you have to build 
RUN yarn install --production
RUN lerna bootstrap
RUN cd /usr/src/app/packages/shared && yarn build
RUN cd /usr/src/app/packages/api && yarn build
###############################################################################
# Step 2 : Run image
FROM node:11
LABEL maintainer="Richard T"
LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="This is our dist docker image"
RUN npm i -g yarn
RUN npm i -g lerna
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL error
ARG PORT=3001
ENV PORT $PORT 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./package* ./
COPY ./lerna.json ./
COPY ./.env ./
COPY ./yarn* ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/packages/shared ./packages/shared
COPY ./packages/api/package* ./packages/api/
COPY ./packages/api/.env* ./packages/api/
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/packages/api ./packages/api
RUN yarn install 
CMD cd ./packages/api && yarn start-production
EXPOSE $PORT
###############################################################################
```